# How to dualboot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd, adapter

I replaced my CD/DVD with a 2nd HDD using an HDD/SSD IDE to SATA adapter rack.
I would like to know if i can have these configuration:

- Windows 8.1 licensed on first hardisk
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the second hardisk (HDD or SSD) located on IDE to SATA adapter rack (former CD/DVD)

I would like to be able to boot both of them, without afecting at all Windows installation (e.g. installating grub or other linux bootloader on Windows hardisk).

Comment: Two hard disks (or SSD's) are not an issue but Windows 8 is.. Read this:- http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: This also relates to your situation:- http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: Perfect, then give it a go @privateoneuser

Comment: 1. The laptop is not UEFI 2. It is crucial that the second HDD/SSD is located on IDE to SATA adapter rack because I already installed Ubuntu there without primary hardisk and it is not booting at all!!!

Comment: Are you able to go into Grub?

Comment: I didn't installed Windows 8.1 yet so I will not ruin the licence after with problems. I only want to have 2 different hardisks as per description if possible! As I mentioned the 2nd hardisk (already installed with Ubuntu) cannot boot - whitout having the primary hardisk operating. It should, isn't it?!

Comment: Maybe its an issue with your Hard-Disk Primary/Slave Configuration. Same happened with me eons ago..

Comment: There is no issue. I, myself, manually removed it!

Comment: Are you trying to say that you're unable to boot into Ubuntu with both the hard disks attached? OR with only the Ubuntu One?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24137/discussion-between-privateoneuser-and-sharad-gautam).

Comment: Ok, meet me [there](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24137/discussion-between-privateoneuser-and-sharad-gautam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed a disk caddy with a PATA/SATA interface, and had booting problems -- grub would freeze up when accessing the disk.  The disk worked fine as a disk, but when present, grub would freeze when accessing it in any way, even just tab completion on the grub command line!  My BIOS did not allow selecting which disk to have first in boot order, and the caddy disk had precedence.  Changing the BIOS presence/absence of a CD drive did not help.  I had Ubuntu on both disks.

---

Oops, found some old notes, couldn't run off the caddy, needed to find a workaround to boot the first disk, then use the disk in the caddy.
 This meant that I could only run the Ubuntu on the internal disk only if grub avoided the caddy disk completely!

A workaround is to boot off something like USB you can put before the hard disk(s).  I could set grub up to run the installation on the internal harddisk, avoiding any reference to the caddy, and that succeeded. The caddy disk may then be mounted and accessed in a normal second disk fashion. There may be other grub modules to include which might fix the problem, but I didn't find anything which worked.

Comment: I will resume to make sure I understand it start=>USB Boot=>Grub Bootloader=> option 1. Windows -hardisk1 or option 2. Ubuntu-SCSI IDE to SATA. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

When going through the interface for installing Ubuntu (after booting the setup form either a USB dirve or CD), you should be able to select "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1". You should be able to select the installation drive as well.

Comment: And what if "the drive" is on SCSI (former CD/DVD location)? It should run smooth or not?

Comment: I'm not overly sure, but having looked around, there isn't much between SATA and SCSI. You should be fine.

Comment: In my BIOS I have Primary Hard Drive and Fixed Bay Device. But it is only informative and I cannot change nothing in there.